# How to read long value sent by Arduino in C

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, c++

I have a quick question regarding this code below in Arduino:

```
Serial.print("0");
Serial.print(5);
Serial.print("0");
Serial.print(1);
Serial.print("0");
Serial.print(5);
Serial.print("0");
Serial.print(1);
Serial.print("0");
Serial.println(5);
```

In C code, currently I'm receiving the message using this method below:

```
int serialport_read_until(int fd, char* buf, char until, int buf_max, int timeout)
{
    char b[1];  // read expects an array, so we give it a 1-byte array
    int i=0;
    do { 
        int n = read(fd, b, 1);  // read a char at a time
        if( n==-1) return -1;    // couldn't read
        if( n==0 ) {
            usleep( 1 * 1000 );  // wait 1 msec try again
            timeout--;
            if( timeout==0 ) return -2;
            continue;
        }
        buf[i] = b[0]; 
        i++;
    } while( b[0] != until && i+1 < buf_max && timeout>0 );

    buf[i] = 0;  // null terminate the string
    return 0;
}
```

In C i defined:

```
char message[13];
uint32_t num;
char until = '\n';

serialport_read_until(fd, message, newLine, sizeof message, 20000);
// the 20000 is timeout in millisec
// this method stores the data in serial buffer into message array

printf("message is %d\n", num);
```

I am expecting a raw value of **0501050105** first.
Then I convert this raw string into **501050105** using:

```
sscanf(message, "%d", &num);
```

Currently it works fine, but I strongly believe it is not the correct way to do it (or rather not the optimized way to do it).

In addition, when i use serialport_read_until() method above, even though i specify the char until as '\n', the method terminates after reading '\r' (leaving the \n in the serial buffer), and the '\n' is only captured in the next method call.

**Q1:** Am i reading the \r\n wrongly from the println (I saw in Arduino documentation that println prints \r\n)? What resulted in C 'cutting off' the message when it detected a \r from Arduino even though I specifically set to kill it only when \n is received?

**Q2:** Instead of printing a string to me and converting it back to integer in C, is there a way for Arduino to send me a long value directly instead? eg 501050105 or 51515. how should I rewrite the serial print or method? And how do i capture that integer correctly in C? If i'm not wrong if a raw integer is print out from Arduino, it converts it into ASCII code. I'm still very new to C and Arduino and hope some guidelines to be given so I can improve on the current coding.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What's the number you are sending? 501050105? or 51515?

Comment: @NickGammon currently we are sending 501050105 but we are thinking of reducing it to 51515 in future. Both will still be long in Arduino

Comment: What I am trying to ask is: What is the "actual" number you are sending? For example, could it be: `5,1,5,1,5`? Are the zeroes part of the number or a delimiter?

Comment: @NickGammon yes we are trying to send 5,1,5,1,5 efficiently from arduino to C!! Not sure if theres any other efficient ways to do it. We currently reserve 2 digits for the 5 different variables, so i split them up with x%100 followed by x/100 and repeat 4 more times

Comment: The commas sounds much more sensible to me. What if you want to send a zero?

Comment: @NickGammon We will never ever send a zero (minimum value is 1). if we were to use comma, whats the efficient way to extract it out? strtoul, sscanf or others?

Comment: If you are always sending one digit, then the simplest is your suggestion of just packing them all together. Then just index into the received array, eg. `message[0]`, `message[1]` and so on. And to convert back to a number, just subtract `'0'` from it.

Comment: @NickGammon ok thanks i will try out later and let you know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> char b[1];  // read expects an array, so we give it a 1-byte array

No, it expects a *pointer* to a destination to store the data. You don't need a 1-entry array - you can simplify your code with:

```
char b;
...
int n = read(fd, &b, 1);  // read a char at a time
...
buf[i] = b;
... etc ...
```

> Currently it works fine, but I strongly believe it is not the correct way to do it (or rather not the optimized way to do it).

C has the function `strtoul()` which is far more efficient that sscanf.

```
uint32_t val = strtoul(buf, NULL, 10);
```

The `10` is the base to convert from, so you could convert hexadecimal (base 16), octal (base 8), etc using it.

> Q1: Am i reading the \r\n wrongly from the println (I saw in Arduino documentation that println prints \r\n)? What resulted in C 'cutting off' the message when it detected a \r from Arduino even though I specifically set to kill it only when \n is received?

You're defining the variable `until` to contain `\n`, yet passing the variable `newLine` to your function. Maybe that has something to do with it?

> Q2: Instead of printing a string to me and converting it back to integer in C, is there a way for Arduino to send me a long value directly instead? eg 501050105 or 51515. how should I rewrite the serial print or method? And how do i capture that integer correctly in C? If i'm not wrong if a raw integer is print out from Arduino, it converts it into ASCII code. I'm still very new to C and Arduino and hope some guidelines to be given so I can improve on the current coding.

You can send a 32-bit value using just 4 bytes. However it's not reliable without implementing a whole protocol around those 4 bytes which, for just 4 bytes, is a bit of a waste. Simplest just to stick to ASCII encoding your data.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! That was a typo! It's `char newLine = '\n';` Not sure why it still cuts at \r. Could it possibly be because of something like this? https://github.com/todbot/arduino-serial/issues/9 Could I be missing something like this? `options.c_iflag &= ~ICRNL; // Don't Map CR to NL`